# getting ? in place of ID while using HibernateCriteria subquery

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am getting a weird issue while using the hibernate Criteria for a inner query.

Below is the code snippet.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Restaurant.class);
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("nid"));
DetachedCriteria innerIDs = DetachedCriteria.forClass(InnerTable.class).setProjection(Property.forName("tempId") );
criteria.add(Subqueries.in("id", innerIDs));
criteria.list()
```

This above code generated the SQL Script as:

```
1.    SELECT columns names
2.    FROM table name
3.    WHERE   ? IN (SELECT   this_.TEMP_ID AS y0_ FROM   global_temp_id this_)
```

In the line# 3, instead of getting the column name, I am getting ? (question mark). I tried even putting Property.forName("id") in `Subqueries.in` instead "id" still the same issue.

> I have not mapped any relation to these 2 tables in hbm.xml files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see is normal. Criteria queries are transformed to SQL queries executed using prepared statements. The id is a parameter of the statement.

If you want to select restaurants whose ID is in the subquery, then you need

```
criteria.add(Subqueries.propertyIn("id", innerIDs));
```

As [the javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Subqueries.html#in%28java.lang.Object,%20org.hibernate.criterion.DetachedCriteria%29) indicates, `in()` considers the first argument as a literal value:

> Creates a criterion which checks that the value of a literal is IN the values in the subquery result.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working. But could not understand the difference between Subqueries.in and Subqueries.propertyIn. Could you please explain bit? When should I use Subqueries.in() ?

Comment: When you want to look for a literal in the result of a subquery. Like in `select restaurant from Restaurant restaurant where 'Michelin' in (select critique.name from Critique critique where critique.restaurant.id = restaurant.id)`